# angularjs ui-grid 3.0 key navigation

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm keen on migrating from ng-grid 2 to the new ui-grid 3.0 replacement. So far things look nice. One thing I can't figure out though is how to enable navigating through the records with the up and down arrows keys. This worked out of the box with ng-grid when multiSelect was set to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ui-grid you have to enable cell-navigation in your markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-cellNav></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaN0Sr0Z4K7YZRrEBRvt?p=preview)

Comment: Works fine. Do you by any chance know how to do a full-row select instead of selecting a cell?

Comment: You mean highlighting the full row while navigating? I'm not sure how to do this. Maybe by changing the row template or using the onNavigate event. I'll have a look at this, but since I'm also pretty new to ui-grid (and drowning in work) I think it's better to open a new question.

Answer (score 5):

I modified mainguy's Plunker a little bit to achieve what you want.

The main difference is to use ui-grid-selection

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection></div>
</div>
```

and 2 options: enableRowHeaderSelection and multiSelect.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
  multiSelect: false
};
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/URPNej?p=preview).

---

**UPDATE**: The below code will help to select the whole row when you use the arrow keys.

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

  gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope,function(newRowCol, oldRowCol){
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(newRowCol.row.entity);
  });
};
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZpG81?p=preview).

Comment: I know about multiselect, but when I include ui.grid.cellNav for key navigation, then one cell is marked and not the whole row. See your modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TOSAbV?p=preview

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question so I updated my answer above.

Comment: Yes. This fits. Just to add that the color of the focused cell was a different one from the selected, so I had to add this in my site css file: .ui-grid-cell-contents:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #c9dde1 !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

[Vipa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710728/angularjs-ui-grid-3-0-key-navigation/26726526#26726526) is almost right, but has one issue: when you click the first time, in any row, always the first row is entirely selected.

To correct this, angular needs one cycle to capture navigate.
My suggestion to improve that answer is to put `.on.navigate.` into $interval:

```
$interval(function() {
  gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope,function(newRowCol, oldRowCol){
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(newRowCol.row.entity);
  });
}, 1);
```

Here is in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Df6Zxc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided are making the actual selection of the row. In case you would like only the highlighting of the entire row instead of only the clicked cell you may update the original `ui-grid.js` and change 1 line of code in the following block:

```
$scope.$on(uiGridCellNavConstants.CELL_NAV_EVENT, function (evt, rowCol, modifierDown) {
  var isFocused = grid.cellNav.focusedCells.some(function(focusedRowCol, index){
    return (focusedRowCol.row === $scope.row && focusedRowCol.col === $scope.col);
   });
   if (isFocused){
     setFocused();
   } else {
     clearFocus();
   }
 });
```

Just replace the `return (focusedRowCol.row === $scope.row && focusedRowCol.col === $scope.col);` with `return (focusedRowCol.row === $scope.row);` and the rest will be done by the original code.